# ASPX Server side comments messing up controls collection

Tags: asp.net, comments

I am having one of the weirdEST issue I have ever faced. Its ridiculous.

Server side comments gets added as a LiteralControl to the original container control. I know it sounds really crazy, but thats what I am experiencing here :(

My environment: Visual studio 2012, IIS 7, .net frameworks 4.0

I am copying my test page here:

Default.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" id="divTest">
       <%--test--%>
       <%--test--%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("divTest Control count: {0}", divTest.Controls.Count));
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The resulting page shows the output:

```
divTest Control count: 3
```

The funniest part is that, I tried to run this same page in 3 other boxes,( with exactly same config/environment) and it worked as expected in 2 of them and the other one showed the same result as mine.  Again, if I change the build target framework version to 2.0, it shows the expected results (divTest Control count: 1). This happens only when I build it in 4.0

Any idea what could be the reason for this odd behaviour? Am i missing something here?

Thanks

Benjamin

Comment: I tried it and got 3 when run through VS and 1 when published. So I wonder if Visual Studio is doing this on purpose.

Comment: what do you mean "on purpose"? whats the purpose here? you mean its a bug?

Comment: One another thing I noticed is that, If I build it in release mode for any target framework ( <complilation debug="false"..), it'll work fine and shows the count as 1 itself.

Comment: I meant Visual Studio doing something internally to keep track of the comments. That's just a guess though.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But it doesn't make any sense to me for adding comments to controls collection, when it doesnt have any state or object level visibility anywhere. I seriously doubt if its visual studio bug itself. I did not receive any response in official Microsoft asp.net forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

The extra LiteralControl is not from comment but white spaces that surrounds it.

Same thing happend to me when switched from VS.NET 2010 to 2013 (yes, just upgraded VS.NET - no change in website target framework - 4.0)

The solution in my case was to use FindControl() method instead of accessing ControlCollection directly by index.